# Downloading a file without extension from a folder to file with extension on browser in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, filestreamresult

There are word files and pdf files stored in a folder without extensions. When we open these files with pdf view or word viewer the corresponding files gets rendered.
Now the requirement is to download these files from .net core application on click of the file name.

Below is the code sample:

```
public IActionResult Download(int Id)
{
     var fileDetails = GetFileDetailsById(Id);
     string fullpath = Path.Combine(_configuration.GetValue<string>("ServerPath:Documents:FolderPath"), FileNameWithoutExtension);
     List<string> lines = new List<string>();
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath);
     while (!reader.EndOfStream)
     {
         lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
     }
     byte[] dataAsBytes = lines.SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s + Environment.NewLine)).ToArray();
     var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(dataAsBytes);
     var contentType = ContentType; // Content ype saved in DB
     var downloadFileName = OriginalFileName;// Original File Name saved in DB
     return File(content, contentType, downloadFileName);
}
```

value of "fullpath" would be "\foldername\filename" without extension.

When the application is run, the files are downloaded without extension.

I would need help in downloading files with extension.

Comment: is it possible to save the `OriginalFileName` with the extension when it is first entered into the database.

Comment: The db has a table which stores file name, extension type and encrypted file name.
the file is then stored with the encrypted file name without extension in the folder

Comment: tried the below code:

`HttpContext.Response.Clear();

 HttpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.{1}", supportingDocument.OriginalFileName, supportingDocument.Content_Type.Extension);
 HttpContext.Response.ContentType = supportingDocument.Content_Type.Description;
HttpContext.Response.SendFileAsync(fileName);`

Comment: instead of reading each line, have you tried reading the files bytes `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilesPath)`

Comment: yes @traveler3468. that still downloads the file w/o exxtension

Comment: you will need to add the extension manually by the sounds of it, what does the `OriginalFileName` currently look like?

Comment: OriginalFileName = "FileName.pdf"

Comment: for pdf files is your `contentType` `application/pdf`?

Comment: `var contentType = fileDetails.Content_Type.Description;`

Comment: yes it would be `application/pdf`

Comment: can't i use the `HttpContext.Response` object to fix this, it downloads files with extension but only for files of pdf type, files are downloaded with partial contents inside of them.

Comment: so when you download the file and open it in file explorer it is corrupt however the original file is ok?

Comment: yes.... i'll share the screenshot of the pdf file downloaded when i use the `HttpContext.Response`

Comment: unable to add screenshot here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help point you in the right direction as from the comments it sounds like you're having trouble with downloading a PDF file even with the extension attached.
Use `byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilesPath)`

Once you have done that create a temp file path 
`string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),$"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()}.pdf");`
After that create the temp file using `FileStream` as well as a `BinaryWriter` and write the bytes to the `BinaryWriter`

```
// Create File Stream,
// Create BinaryWriter So We Can Write A PDF.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Create))
using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    binaryWriter.Write(bytes);
}
```

you can then return the `tempPath` to the caller and read the bytes when required.
If you need to display the PDF in the browser you will need to attach `application/pdf` to the ContentType in the `Response Headers` so the browser knows how to handle the request.

Comment: Will quickly check on this @traveler3468